# A App deep link to B App show Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid site

Tags: ios, deep-linking, url-scheme, ios-universal-links

I have a question about deep link.

And I also used URL schemes to open B App like this.
[image]

But If when my B App doesn't install in my phone, it will show this message.

`openInbox://xxxxxxxxx`

`Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid site`

How to fix this issue?

Or how to use universal link to fix this issue?

Comment: A universal link should resolve this issue, but it requires server-side code. Using a 3rd party service like Branch.io to handle the server side of the implementation is very common.